# How to put a delegate method into a new thread?

Tags: iphone

I have implement the delegate method:

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream*)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode;
```

and for every one second this method will be called,and this method will do many things,so I need to put this method into a new thread,so that the UI thread won't be blocked.
and I also want to know what the above delegate method is called by ?system?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to perform a task in a background thread (note: you can't touch the UI in this thread!  You must schedule calls to update the UI on the main thread) is:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doInBackground) withObject:nil]
```

Comment: can you give me more details?